# Threading-Safe std:list C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, mutex

I am new to multi-threading and I am trying to simply make some std:lists thread-safe. Would it be enough to do mutex.lock() and mutex.unlock() whenever an item is being added or removed to the lists? Again, I am only trying to make them thread-safe.

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

You must protect all access to the list in order to be safe. While reading from a list without a lock will not corrupt the list, if the list is modified while another thread is reading from it, either thread could become corrupt (i.e. crash, or produce incorrect results).

You must hold the lock for the entire span of code that you expect the contents to be stable for. If another thread can erase or reorder any element at any time, then this includes any time you have live iterators to its contents. If there are restrictions as to which threads can manipulate which elements, the locking requirements can be relaxed with respect to holding live iterators.

Using [std::lock_guard](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) can help make sure you manage the lock correctly. Just create an instance of it at the beginning of any scope that will manipulate your list, and at the end of the scope it will automatically unlock, even if the scope exits via exception.

Comment: Actually, the second paragraph is wrong. List iterators are in fact stable. I don't see a trivial edit to make that paragraph right, though. It might be best to rewrite it.

Comment: @MSalters In what sense? If other threads are potentially modifying the list, the iterators could be come invalid or the things those iterators refer to could change in ways that cause your code to break. Maybe *stable* is not the right word, but I think the statement generally correct.

Comment: @MSalters In my first paragraph, only the reading thread would become corrupt as the example did not state that multiple unprotected writers where involved. This comes from the OP who stated that he was only going to lock modifications, not reads.

Comment: @nate Iterators are deemed valid until <X,Y,Z> happens and "having something other than X,Y,Z happen in another thread" does not count. You do not need to protect the lifetime of your iterators for multi-threading reasons. This is particularly useful for list iterators, for which the list X,Y,Z is very short. Probably about the only thing lists are good for tbh

Comment: What if the iterators where the reads happen are const and the owner of the list only appends or prepends, guaranteeing no modifications of pre-existing data?

Comment: If you know that another thread won't write to subsets of the list you are reading it is safe

Answer (score 3):

Note that C++ does not define *thread-safe*, but defines *data race* which is a condition that occurs when multiple threads access the same object and at least one of them is a writer.

You can use a mutex to make member functions of `std::list<>` data race free. You can even do that for any arbitrary object with [Wrapping C++ Member Function Calls technique by Bjarne Stroustrup](http://www.stroustrup.com/wrapper.pdf). This is known as *internal locking*, meaning that the object maintains its own mutex.

This method does not make data race free leaked references to the internal state of the object, such as references, pointers and iterators. For example, when you iterate over the list you do not want another thread to invalidate your iterator by removing the element, hence you will have to keep the mutex locked till the iteration has completed.

Also, in many useful scenarios it is more than just one object that needs to be changed atomically. In this case you need one mutex that serializes access to multiple objects.

Comment: @Slava Obviously, member functions that leak pointers, references and iterators cannot be made thread-safe. But you did not even bother to spell out why, so your comment is next to useless.

Comment: OP asks if he can make `std::list<>` thread safe, almost all access to data in list requires iterator (except trivial cases like front and back), so no you cannot make `std::list` thread safe just locking mutex inside list methods.

Comment: @Slava That depends on the usage pattern. For example, if `std::list<>` is used as a queue or stack, only `push_back`, `pop_front`, `pop_back` are used.

Comment: You cannot say that something is thread safe depending on usage pattern. Otherwise everything is thread safe, like if you only read data from `std::map` it is fine then `std::map` is thread safe.

Comment: @Slava The C++ standard does not provide a definition of _thread-safe_. There are _data races_ though and particular usage can cause data races or not.

Comment: If so then your answer is not only incorrect, it is also misleading.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, yes. If every thread/path that modifies or reads the list locks the same mutex before doing so, then access to the list can be considered thread safe.

Note that caveats apply if someone holds on to iterators, references or pointers to list items outside the scope of the lock. In that case you are no longer safe.

Comment: The problem is that OPs want to hold mutex inside list itself and make it thread safe.

Comment: @Slava that was/is not clear to me the way the question was worded.

Answer (score 0):

> Would it be enough to do mutex.lock() and mutex.unlock() whenever an item is being added or removed to the lists?

No, you have to synchronize all access including reading data. You may use read/write lock to optimize multiple readers case, but price you pay for more complex locking may eat all benefits you get, it depends on particular situation.

If the question is "can I put a mutex inside a list and make it thread safe?" then answer is no, you cannot. If you look into `std::list` interface you can see that almost any access to data that list holds is done through iterators, so making `std::list` thread safe will require to make those iterators thread safe which is not doable (ie what will you do if iterator that points to deleted data is derefernced).